# GeoTIFF issue with opening in PIL

Tags: python, image, scipy, tiff, geotiff

Everytime I open an GeoTIFF image of a orthophoto in python (tried PIL, matplotlib, scipy, openCV) the image screws up. Some corners are beeing cropped , however the image remains its original shape. If I manually convert the tif to for instance a png in Photoshop and load it, it does work correctly. So it seems like PIL has some trouble handling tif files with objects that not fill the entire canvas. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

*Part of original Image:*

[image: Part of original Image]

*After opening:*

[image: After opening]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been really nice if you put the link of the figure that you are using (if it's free). I downloaded a sample GeoTIFF image from [here](http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif), and I used [gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) to open it.

The shape of the `geotiff.ReadAsArray()` is `(3, 1024, 2048)` so I convert it to `(1024, 2048, 3)` (RGB) and open it with `imshow`:

```
import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

geotiff = gdal.Open('/home/vafanda/Downloads/test.tif')
geotiff_arr= geotiff.ReadAsArray()
print np.shape(geotiff_arr)
geotiff_shifted = np.rollaxis(geotiff_arr,0,3)
print "Dimension converted to: "
print np.shape(geotiff_shifted)
plt.imshow(geotiff_shifted)
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @seanzand No problem. just for your information, if you are satisfied with an answer you can accept it :)

Comment: @seanzand  no I mean you can accept the answer the solution in the answer worked for you. take a look at [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwTL.png) for example,  if you click on the checkmark of an answer, it will be "accepted"